# Twitter API increase rate limit

Tags: api, twitter, rate-limiting

I need Twitter data for my master thesis. I want to apply for the academic access, however I read that there is a rate limit of 300 requests/15 minutes.
How can I understand that, I would need almost a year to pull 10M tweets? Is there a way to pull more tweets in these 15 minutes?

Background: I want to get all tweets referring to specific companies, so I want to search for cashtags.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it’s probably too late but i’m undergoing something similar and found a really useful resource called SNScrape. This python module allows for unlimited tweet search requests without the use of the api. Below I’v attached a useful video which I stumbled across. Hope this helps.

https://youtu.be/jtIMnmbnOFo

Comment: In the end I've also used snscrape and it worked really well! Anyway thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It would only take almost a year if each request was a single Tweet. I haven't looked at the API, but they surely have endpoints that allow you to get lists of tweets matching your criteria in a single request. You should be fine with that rate limit for your research.